# Jquery - set a variable with a decimal in front

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Jquery, how do you take a variable and set a second variable with a decimal in front of the value of the first variable.

For example I have a variable that is set from a form input values. I named this variable `subTotal`. Now I want to take that variable and set another variable with a decimal in front of it so I can calculate a percentage by multiplying another input value.

So here is some of the code for example

```
 var subTotal = self.calculateTotalFor(elems);
 total += (quantity - 1) * NewVariable;
```

- `self.calculateTotalFor(elems);` comes from the input on the form
- `NewVariable` would be Subtotal with a decimal in front.

Comment: `var NewVariable = parseFloat("." + Subtotal);`

Comment: @jasonscript ya that works, why dont you put that as an answer and I will give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var NewVariable = parseFloat("." + Subtotal);
```

- This will take `"."` and your `Subtotal` value and perform a string
  append
- `parseFloat` will convert the string to a floating point number

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var subTotal = self.calculateTotalFor(elems), total = 0;
total += (quantity - 1) * NewVariable;

or

total += parseFloat((quantity - 1) * NewVariable);
```

Comment: Jason has already answered it in a comment, but I voted your question up because it can work also. Thanks for your help